# Issue on Drawing Shape Using Pure CSS3

Tags: css, css-shapes

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/x9dq2xn7/) and let me know how I can change the shape tbe look like below image

[image]

and here is my CSS properties

```
#shape
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    background: #EAD2BA;
    /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 225px;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```css
body{padding:40px;}
#shape
{
 width: 500px;
 height: 350px;
 background: #EAD2BA;
 /*border-radius*/
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 225px;
 margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="shape"></section>
```

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this with border-radius.

Comment: Thanks Paulie but is it possible with CSS or not?

Comment: Possibly but,frankly, it's probably not worth the effort. Use an image or an SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the exact shape that you are looking for but you'll figure it out from this anyway.

first of all, to make that shape, you will need more than 1 shape, so using something like #shape:after in your css can do that.

here's the code that I used to create a similar shape:

```
body{padding:40px;}
#shape {
width: 20;
height: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-left: 50px solid transparent;
border-right: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
border-top: 50px solid #EAD2BA;
position: relative;
}
#shape:after {
width: 473px;
height: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
border-bottom: 100px solid #EAD2BA;
border-top: 100px solid transparent;
position: absolute;
content: "";
top: -100px;
left: -36px;
}
```

and here's a fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/x9dq2xn7/1/

Comment: Thanks Kristofer Aron Sverrisson this is very helpful